# Save user activity to text file

Tags: php

In PHP, I want to save messages to a text file and read the log file using php.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function LogUserActivity($LogFile, $Activity){
    $UserIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $TimeRef = date('d-m-Y H:i T');

    $Handle = fopen($LogFile, 'a');
    $Data = $UserIp.'|'.$TimeRef.'|'.$Activity.'~';
    fwrite($Handle, $Data);
    fclose($Handle);
}

function ReadUserActivity($LogFile){
    global $log;
    $LogFile = file_get_contents($LogFile);
    $ExplodedLogFile = explode("~", $LogFile);
    $ArrayNum = count($ExplodedLogFile);

    $i = 0;
    while ( $i <= $ArrayNum ){
        $log[$i] = explode("|", $ExplodedLogFile[$i]);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code looks pretty self-explanatory, what trouble are you having with it?

Comment: `file_put_contents("/tmp/stuff.txt", "penguins", FILE_APPEND);`  Will append the string: 'penguins' to /tmp/stuff.txt, creating the file if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `LogUserActivity` at the beginning of every script, passing it the file you want to write to and some message to yourself. E.g.:

```
<?php
include('the-file-where-you-put-these-functions.php');
LogUserActivity('/tmp/example.log', 'Porkchop sandwitches!');
// the rest of your script
?>
```

Call the other function in the script you're gonna use to inspect the logs. It will set the $log variable which you can then print out however you want.

**Or just use this single liner:**

```
<?php
file_put_contents("/tmp/stuff.txt", "penguins", FILE_APPEND); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a mySQL database:

http://www.thesitewizard.com/faqs/what-is-mysql-database.shtml

But if you insist on using that, here are some comments to help you understand..

```
<?php
//create file ($LogFile -> filename, $Activity -> type of activity)
function LogUserActivity($LogFile, $Activity){
    //get user's ip
    $UserIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    //get time
    $TimeRef = date('d-m-Y H:i T');
    //create file
    $Handle = fopen($LogFile, 'a');
    //file contents
    $Data = $UserIp.'|'.$TimeRef.'|'.$Activity.'~';
    //write data to file
    fwrite($Handle, $Data);
    //close file
    fclose($Handle);
}

//read data from file ($LogFile -> filename)
function ReadUserActivity($LogFile){
    //variable for storing data on file
    global $log;
    //function to get log file's data
    $LogFile = file_get_contents($LogFile);
    //separate each entry and put it in an array
    $ExplodedLogFile = explode("~", $LogFile);
    //determine number of logs
    $ArrayNum = count($ExplodedLogFile);
    //incrementable variable
    $i = 0;
    //loop to search through logs
    while ( $i <= $ArrayNum ){
        //separate each log into the three parts it has and put them in an array inside the main array
        $log[$i] = explode("|", $ExplodedLogFile[$i]);
        //incrememnt i
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
```